# Google cloud speech-to-text SpeechClient.Recognize in Android does not return

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to do a speech-to-text recognition with Google Cloud speech recognition V1 API and find that the function SpeechClient.Recognize does not return. Do anybody know the reason?
This is the code:

```
_client = SpeechClient.Create();
_config = new RecognitionConfig
{
    Encoding = AudioEncoding.Linear16,
    SampleRateHertz = App.Config.SampleRate,
    LanguageCode = "es-ES",
};
_audio = new byte[0];

---

private void _vcAudioEvent(object source, VcEventArgs ev)
{
    int i;
    byte[] buf;
    byte[] bufAux;
    System.Threading.Thread th;

    if (ev.Audio != null)
    {
        _isSpeech = true;
        _tmrSilence.Start();
        buf = new byte[ev.Audio.Length * 2];

        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(ev.Audio, 0, buf, 0, buf.Length);

        bufAux = (byte[])_audio.Clone();
        _audio = new byte[bufAux.Length + buf.Length];
        Array.Copy(bufAux, 0, _audio, 0, bufAux.Length);
        Array.Copy(buf, 0, _audio, bufAux.Length, buf.Length);

    }

}

---

RecognitionAudio audio;
RecognizeResponse response;

audio = RecognitionAudio.FromBytes(_audio);

response = _client.Recognize(_config, audio);
```

Comment: I forgot to say that the application is in c# in Xamarin-Android